# Having a instance of SQLiteOpenHelper in Singleton Class

Tags: android

i have a singleton class with an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class AppManager { //Singleton

    private static AppManager _instance = null;

    private static DataSource datasource;
    ....

    public static AppManager getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new AppManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    private AppManager() {
        datasource = new DataSource(App.get());
    }
    ....
}
```

to get the context i made a file named App.java:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
    private static App instance;

    public static App get() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

the DataSource file looks like this:

```
public class DataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public DataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
    public Line createLine(int ID) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("ID", ID);

    database.insertWithOnConflict("LINES", null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

    Cursor cursor = database.query("LINES", columns_LINES, "ID = " + ID, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursorToLine(cursor);
    }
 }
```

now my problem is, when i call `AppManager.getInstance().getDB().createLine(1);` i get an NullPointerException. I think this is because i declared the DataSource in the Singleton class. I dont want to make the DataSource to a Singleton class, but is there another way to have an instance of the DataSource Class?

logcat says this:

```
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at com.testapp.android.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:26)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at com.testapp.android.AppManager.<init>(AppManager.java:28)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at com.testapp.android.AppManager.getInstance(AppManager.java:21)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at com.testapp.android.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:76)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
09-16 00:18:25.604: E/AndroidRuntime(11858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you provide logcat

Comment: ok, it's definitely beacuse of App.get()

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `open()` in the beginning of the method `createLine(int)`. Your `database` is still null.

Comment: even when i call `datasource.open();` in my singleton class, it throws an error

Comment: with `AppManager.getInstance().getDB().open();` bevore `AppManager.getInstance().getDB().createline(1)` its also the same